# Sharepoint 2010 Claim Based Authentication is Not working - (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am working in SharePoint 2010. Claim based authentication is not working for SharePoint web application. It gives (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: you have to set `CustomError=Off` in `web.config` to show error message details